# Gotta make some Dosh!

Tags: fantasy-life

Fantasy Life's currency is Dosh. I know there are a few ways to make Dosh but I am wondering what is a good solid way to do it. You can go around and gather up ingredients and either sell them or craft them into other items and sell those. You can buy ingredients from many of the shops in town and craft them into others.

It is just that the gathering of ingredients takes quite a while, as you have to run around a certain distance to get items to respawn and they are not in large quantities. For example, some quantities range from 1 - 6 depending on what you are talking about. The profit margins on buying -> crafting -> selling are often very minor; for instance, an egg sells for 20 Dosh, a hard boiled egg can then be sold back for 30 Dosh regardless of normal or superior quality.

So what is a good way to do this? Should I just go grind baddies, are there certain items that are more profitable (I have started as a cook and am now moving on to an Angler in order to catch the fish I need for recipes)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Questing:**

One of the best ways to get Dosh currently in the game is just to continue the quest chain. You will start to get large amounts of dosh (I'm talking 2000-5000 dosh per quest) later in the game.

**The Blacksmith Profession:**

Another way is to craft with the blacksmith profession, and crafting Gladiator gear, specifically Gladiator Pants. You can easily almost double your profit by buying platinum bars and turning them into Gladiator Pants, usually costs about 2800 dosh and sells for around 5k. The more you work with the blacksmith skill, the higher chance of creating a very high quality item which sells for even more profit!

**General Crafting:**

Crafting high-quality items in general is a good way to earn dosh fast, and can easily be done by anyone with some skill/experience. Make sure to try and see what items are the best, and how much your going to profit with it.

**Collecting the materials yourself:**

Collecting the materials yourself will always profit farther, but make sure to remember the time requirement you need to get the materials required. Personally I don't find it worth it to gather materials, since you can make way more dosh per hour just crafting the recipes.

Comment: Yeah I figured I am going slow. I am still in the first town and just enjoying trying out all the lives, but it seemingly takes forever to get enough Dosh to move out of the Attic. It would seem that a bit of advancement might see larger profit margins in general, both questing and the materials on hand?

Comment: In-demand items? What market are you referring to?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Become an alchemist and make flasks. The higher level flasks cost around 2k for mats but sell for 7-10k

Answer (score 1):

Figured since I was looking for the answer to this question myself that I'd chip my two cents in now that I (literally) just achieved the 1,000,000 Dosh bliss bonus.

I started as a Merc, got Creator rank some time ago.  Questing, killing, selling off materials, turning in bounties ... None of these are particularly time effective means of making Dosh.  Probably made about 300k Dosh all told after expenses -- namely potions and equipment.

I was then a Paladin, got Master rank pretty quick.  Same story as the Merc, but with less time spent and more Dosh spent.

Started life as a Woodcutter, Master rank also, didn't bother selling the wood as I was saving for what I presumed I'd need as a Carpenter, which led to a negative cash flow.

Went on to the Miner Life where I've made it through Expert rank so far.  Got tired of it when I reached the goal to mine 100 times, figured I could keep working toward that from another life.

When I first tried my hand at crafting as a Blacksmith things got interesting.  I realized at that point that I'd need items crafted as a Carpenter to efficiently craft as a Blacksmith, so I became a Carpenter; then I realized that I'd need items from the Tailor Life to be an efficient Carpenter; and as a Tailor I saw that in fact all three provide for one another, irritating but effective I suppose.  Adept Blacksmith, Apprentice Carpenter, Apprentice Tailor, negative cash flow and somewhat irritated having spent the money to switch around stats a couple times at this point.

Tried hand at Wizard for a bit until Adept before deciding to go back to the gathering/crafting Lives to try to find a way to make Dosh.

Became an Angler, had a hard time finding a particular fish in the Elderwood, so went on to Cook.

That brings me back around to the question; while I haven't tried Archer or Alchemist yet, I've found a fair way to make Dosh by being a Cook that you can start as an Apprentice.  The recipe for Rustic Trout requires one Elderwood Trout for 120 Dosh from the fish vendor in Castelle, one Carrot for 20 Dosh from the vegetables vendor in Castelle, and three Grass Plains Barley for 20 Dosh each from the vegetables vendor in Castelle.  Altogether, that's 200 Dosh as an investment.  Regular Rustic Trout sells for 270 Dosh each, a net profit of 70 Dosh; Superior Rustic Trout sells for 320 Dosh each, a net profit of 120 Dosh.  I purchased 495 Elderwood Trout (5 sets of 99), 495 Carrots, and 1,485 Grass Plains Barley (15 sets of 99) for a total of 99,000 Dosh.  I went and cooked bulk on Auto+ after I achieved it, and all told in under 45 minutes I sold all the Rustic Trout back -- 77 regular and 460 Superior -- for a gross profit of 167990, subtracting the original investment of 99000 leaving a net profit of 68990.

Okay, so I'm particularly awesome.  Even so:  making Rustic Trout you achieve a net profit of 70 Dosh per dish, so even if you aren't good enough to make Superior dishes or attain any extra, the 99000 Dosh will net you at least 34650 in profit, which is more than even three high level bounties will return, probably in less time as well, and without spending money on potions.

As Julia Child would say -- Bon appétit!

tl;dr craft the ready to purchase recipe that gives you as much net Dosh as possible in as much bulk as you can afford

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten a fair bit of cash by turning in bounties.  Just got to West Grassy Plains, and an Earth Tree bounty gave me 1.5k, which is a lot for me.
The big disadvantage is that you can only carry 3, and having to find a NPC to turn it in.
I think higher-level crafting will be better income overall, but bounties can provide a nice supplement.

Comment: I was actually doing this in the mountains I can not recall the name of right now but there was a regional bounty collector perched up top right next to where quite a few of them appear. This is indeed a nice steady flow of Dosh but I have also found crafting to be more effective, even at lower profit margins. Buy 100 of something, cook/craft it into 100 of something 10 at a time, and sell it off.. it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i could think of is looting inside Cave of Bones.
The Skeletons there drops Sack of Gold pretty much all the time, there are tons of Skeletons and they are easy to kill.
When you sell the Sacks of Gold you can make a pretty decent amount of Dosh.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to have DLC and collect flowers, butterflies, goldweeds...(etc.) on Orgin Island. They all sell for a pretty good price... (DLC is only 8.99 in USA.)